# How to fix arabic diacritics displaying properly in Zekr

Tags: 16.04, fonts, arabic

I install **[Zekr](http://www.zekr.org/)** *Qur'an study software* from Ubuntu Software on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

In order to run, I must install this

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

after **Zekr** can run, I got diacritics *(harakaat/tashkeel)* not displaying properly.

[image: zekr]

---

I think, it can be fixed by change the font. **Tools** > **Options** > **View**

- Setting View **before** I changed

  [image: before changed]
- Setting View **after** I changed *quran_fontName* add `KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS`

  [image: after]

  **RESULT :** Diacritics still not displaying properly

  [image: after view]

---

**P.S.**

I have installed this font `KFGQPC Uthmanic Script HAFS`, `KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh`, `Scheherazade`, `mry_KacstQurn`, `me_quran` and change *quran_fontName* with that font. but the result is same, diacritics not displaying properly.

any ideas ?

Thank You so much for help

Comment: Have you tried to make use of the standard fonts for Arabic in Ubuntu? `sudo apt install fonts-arabeyes fonts-kacst`

Comment: I have tried but not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

- This should be reported as bug to Zekr project.

  As I had tried similar experiment before, I expect the developer is trying to make diacritics (harakaat/tashkeel) with different color than letters.

  So Zekr prints letters without diacritics on a layer, then diacritics on another layer.

  Which may work for some font/rendering-kit combinations but not for all. Diacritics are not in the correct position with respect each letter.
- Try remove all fonts from that priority list of `quran_fontName` put only: `Scheherazade` or `me_quran` .